# nginx 500 (24: too many open files)

Tags: nginx, 500-error

*[I posted this on the Nginx forums, but had no responses a week later, so trying here]*

I am a Linux and Nginx novice, but have learnt enough to get it installed and running and working as a simple reverse proxy for two internal webservers. This has been running fine for months, but I recently started getting 500 errors.

Here is the recent output of `/var/log/nginx/error.log`
(I have replaced our company name with "companyname.com" and replaced our public WAN IP address with

```
2020/02/10 15:17:49 [alert] 1069#1069: *1011 socket() failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.10.10.1, server: web1.companyname.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "https://<WANIP>:443/", host: "web1.companyname.com"

2020/02/10 15:21:41 [alert] 1069#1069: *2022 socket() failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.10.10.1, server: web2.companyname.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "https://<WANIP>:443/", host: "web2.companyname.com"

2020/02/10 15:33:28 [alert] 1084#1084: *19987 socket() failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.10.10.1, server: web2.companyname.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "https://<WANIP>:443/", host: "web2.companyname.com"

2020/02/10 15:34:16 [alert] 1084#1084: *39974 socket() failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.10.10.1, server: web1.companyname.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "https://<WANIP>:443/", host: "web1.companyname.com"

2020/02/10 15:50:30 [error] 1086#1086: *1 client intended to send too large body: 4294967295 bytes, client: 176.58.124.134, server: london.companyname.com, request: "GET /msdn.cpp HTTP/1.1", host: "<WANIP>"

2020/02/10 16:32:56 [alert] 1086#1086: *19989 socket() failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.10.10.1, server: web1.companyname.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "https://<WANIP>:443/", host: "web1.companyname.com"
```

I have added the following to the end of `/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
nginx soft nofile 10000
nginx hard nofile 30000
```

I have added the following to `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
fs.file-max=70000
```

...And rebooted. However, I'm getting the same problem immediately after a reboot.

Interestingly the IP address that appears in the log "`176.58.124.134`" I don't recognise and a quick google search suggests this is an abusive IP address. I can block at the firewall, but I'm not sure that's the problem.

Any tips, suggestions are grealy appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You update `ulimits` but did you change also `worker_rlimit_nofile` in nginx config file?

Comment: Yes, when troubleshooting this last week I added the following line

"worker_rlimit_nofile 20000;"

Comment: And did you restart the service?

Comment: Yep. I have just restarted now to be sure. But otherwise the server has been rebooted a few times in the last week.

Comment: What's the output of ulimit -n ?

Comment: output of "ulimit -n" is 1024

Answer (score 20):

Your **nginx** server is not keeping up with the number of requests arriving. More precisely it lacks available file descriptors to open connections to the upstream.

These are regulated by three parameters:

1. The per-system limit in [/proc/sys/fs/file-max](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/fs.html#file-max-file-nr), which limits the maximum number of **fd**s for the whole system. Don't change it, the default is high enough (`800000` on my small server).
2. The per-process hard limit ([RLIMIT_NOFILE](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getrlimit.3p.html)), which can be only set by **root** (or a process having `CAP_SYS_RESOURCES`). This is usually quite high (`ulimit -Hn`, around `1000000`), so no need to increase it. If you want to increase it the **pam_limit.so** configuration `/etc/security/limits.conf` will **not** help you, as **nginx** is started by **systemd** (I have to guess, since you don't mention your distribution), which does not use PAM. You'll need to edit the `nginx.service` file instead:

   ```
   systemctl edit --full nginx.service
   ```

   and add the following line to the `[Service]` section:

   ```
   LimitNOFILE=your_limit
   ```
3. The per-process soft limit. **nginx** can increase it itself with the directive mentioned by Romeo:

   ```
   worker_rlimit_nofile = your_limit;
   ```

Each limit can not be higher, than the ones in the previous points.

However, unless your website became extremely popular overnight, it is much more probable that it is experiencing a DDOS attack. You can mitigate it by limiting the number of connections per client using the [http_limit_conn](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html) module. The example configuration in the documentation should directly apply to your case:

```
http {
    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=addr:10m;
    limit_conn addr 10;
    ...
```

which will limit the number of connections per IP address to 10. On most distributions you can put the two `limit_*` directives in a separate file (e.g. `/etc/nginx/conf.d/limit.conf`) without modifying the main `nginx.conf`.

Comment: Thanks. I added the two http_limit_conn lines you referred to into the nginx.conf, then restarted. I'm now getting a slightly different error when browing to the website "503: Service Temporarily Unavailable".

error.log shows 

`_2020/02/19 16:44:22 [error] 1091#1091: *23 limiting connections by zone "addr", client: 10.10.10.1, server: web1.companyname.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", host: "web1.companyname.com"_`

where did I go wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing, it is working as intended: limiting every IP address to 10 connections, afterwards it returns `503` errors. What's on `10.10.10.1`? Is it another proxy or does it need to make many requests to your **nginx**?

Comment: I see. Thanks. 10.10.10.1 is our firewall (gateway on Nginx server). By the way, the access.log shows around 20 connections in the last 2 hours, so its by no means a busy server. Around 10 of those are from 10.10.10.1, the rest are from external IPs which appear to be malicious, based on the URLs they are requesting.

Comment: You should probably configure the Nginx on the gateway to send the real IP of the client to the internal Nginx with: `proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;` (cf. [proxy_set_header](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header)) on the gateway and `set_real_ip_from 10.10.10.1;` (cf. [set_real_ip_from](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html#set_real_ip_from)) on the internal Nginx. This way you'll have 10 connections per real IP and not 10 for all the requests proxied by `10.10.10.1`.

Comment: LimitNOFILE=70000 fix the issue

Comment: this stackoverflow answer on systemd is similiar and has some other details too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849331/how-to-set-nginx-max-open-files/36423859#36423859

Answer (score 1):

I saw this message in Nginx logs when I had the error in proxy configuration - by mistake I put Nginx port number in proxy_pass directive (instead of the port of the upstream services) and as a result any request sent to Nginx was looping through until the server ran out of workers due to too many opened connections which actually count as files. Another symptom of this mistake was a growing Nginx access log where each line had one more occurrence of the IP address than the previous one. The problem was gone after I fix the config file.
I hope this helps someone.